# Telerik Extensions for Razor View Engine

Tags: razor

I am using MVC 3 Razor View engine in my project.Does any of you know is there any Telerik extensions ( or any other third party extensions) that i can use to display the folder strucure of a couple of specific folders on the server where  the application  will be hosted ( like we see the folders and subfolders in windows explorer on the left pane and  folders/files on the right pane) on the razor view. User should be able to move/Copy/Rename a file inside a folder to a   destination folder of his/her choice. Does anybody know of any  third party extensions to achieve this?

Thanks in advance
RJ

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this one. telerik treeview 
if it's not it, I am sure if you contacted them they could help you (or not).

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/treeview